# What triggers this screen prompt "Screen used by <username> on host01."?

Tags: gnu-screen, password

Every now and then some key combination clears my working (Gnu) screen and brings up this message:

```
Screen used by <username> on host01
Password:
```

What key combination causes this and what does it signify?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [this source](http://www.bartbania.com/raspberry_pi/linux-screen/#lock) it's the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>x</kbd>.

It signifies locking the `screen` and unlocking it with your password.

Comment: @vfclists, if you find this disruptive, you can add `bind x` to `~/.screenrc` so that key combination will no longer work.

Comment: Windows 10, (Linode) doesnt work.. can't exit ...

Comment: Debian, doesn't exit. I need to close whole tab with screen. Can only kill process with SIGKILL. (kill -9 {PID}) ... and it will break the input of current tab of console. How to get rid of it?

Comment: What happens if the user has no password?, for example, when he logs in with an SSH key.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of locking feature you might set LOCKPRG variable to /bin/false.

```
LOCKPRG=/bin/false
export LOCKPRG
```